# SQL Percentage of Occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on some SQL code as part of my University work. The data is factitious just to be clear. I'm trying to count the occurances of `1` & `0` in the SQL table `Fact_Stream`, this is stored in the `Free_Stream` column/attribute as a Boolean/bit value.

As calculations cant be made on bit values (at least in the way I'm trying) I've converted the value to an integer -- Just to be clear on that. The table contains information on a streaming companies streams, a `1` indicates the stream was free of charge, a `0` indicates the stream was paid for. My code:

```
SELECT Fact_Stream.Free_Stream, ((CAST(Free_Stream AS INT)) / COUNT(*) * 100) As 'Percentage of Streams'
FROM Fact_Stream
GROUP BY Free_Stream
```

The result/output is nearly where I want it to be, but it doesn't display the percentage correctly.

Output:

[image]

Using MS SQL Management Studio | MS SQL Server 2012 (I believe)

Comment: your equation is dividing the identifier (1 or 0) by the number of streams for each one, instead of dividing the count of free or paid by the total count

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment @JenR , I see what you mean but I dont know how to put that into SQL??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentage should be based on all rows, so you need to divide the count per 1/0 by a count of all rows. The easiest way to get this is utilizing a Windowed Aggregate Function:

```
SELECT Fact_Stream.Free_Stream,
   100.0 * COUNT(*)        -- count per bit
   / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () -- sum of those counts = count of all rows
   As "Percentage of Streams"
FROM Fact_Stream
GROUP BY Free_Stream
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `INT`s as a devisor and devidened(not sure I am correct with namings). So the result is also `INT`. Just cast one of those to decimal(notice how did I change to `100.0`). Also you should debide count of elements in group to total count of rows in the table:

```
select Free_Stream, 
       (count(*) / (select count(*) from Free_Stream)) * 100.0 as 'Percentage of Streams'
from Fact_Stream
group by Free_Stream
```

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is dividing the identifier (1 or 0) by the number of streams for each one, instead of dividing the count of free or paid by the total count.  One way to do this is to get the total count first, then use it in your query:

```
declare @totalcount real;
select @totalcount = count(*) from Fact_Stream;

SELECT Fact_Stream.Free_Stream, 
    (Cast(Count(*) as real) / @totalcount)*100 AS 'Percentage of Streams'
FROM Fact_Stream
group by Fact_Stream.Free_Stream
```