# Display percentage of values in the table - even of missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, percentage

I have a following table called **Test**:

```
Id                                   | Value
---------------------------------------------
019D9E52-41D1-45DF-81B6-C7CC484115A7 |   1
262640CA-65C2-4E30-8654-E187ACA1EEF4 |   1
53710AFC-4E19-4B1C-B68B-CDB713EC3D62 |   2
8FF7E77C-D04C-4961-82D9-87C2E5A1A096 |   2
```

And there is a view called **TestView**:

```
Value
------
 1
 2
 3
```

These are just pseudo code examples.

Now, I want to select percentage of all the values from the **Test** table, and if value from the **TestView** is not in the **Test** table I just want to display 0.

Here's the expected result:

```
Value | Percentage
-------------------
  1   |      50
  2   |      50
  3   |      0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bf8b6/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select tv.value, count(t.id) * 1.0 / sum(count(t.id)) over () as ratio
from testview tv left join
     test t
     on tv.value = t.value
group by tv.value
order by tv.value;
```

Note:  This gives the ratio rather than the percentage, simply because I think a number between 0 and 1 is more useful.  Of course, you can multiply by 100.0 instead of 1.0 to get a range from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the percentage with something like this:

```
SELECT value,
   100.0 * COUNT(*)        -- count per bit
   / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () -- sum of those counts = count of all rows
   As "Percentage"
FROM Test
GROUP BY value
```

In case of any doubts, just take a look at this: [SQL Percentage of Occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926712/sql-percentage-of-occurrences)

Comment: yea, I already knew how to take percentage, but forgot to put it in the fiddle, my bad..